# RxJS in AngularJS Services

Tags: angularjs, rxjs

I'm learning RxJS and am trying to implement it in one of my existing applications.  First thing I am trying to do is remove rootscope.broadcast/emit methods and replace them with BehaviorSubjects.  This has worked fine if those events are subscribed to inside a controller.  However, if I try to subscribe to those events in a service, they never fire.  I can move the exact same subscription into a component/controller/etc and it works fine.

Is there a reason for this or should I be able to do this and I am just doing something wrong?

**UPDATE 1**

I have an event service that maintains events run at the top of the application like so:

```
(function () {
"use strict";
angular.module("app.common").service("eventService", EventService);  
function EventService($window) {
"ngInject";

var defaultBehaviorSubjectValue = null;

var service = {
  activate: activate,
  onLogin: new Rx.BehaviorSubject(defaultBehaviorSubjectValue),                     //onnext by authService.login
  onLogout: new Rx.BehaviorSubject(defaultBehaviorSubjectValue),                    //onnext by authService.logout   
  isOnline: new Rx.BehaviorSubject(defaultBehaviorSubjectValue)                    //onnext by authService.logout         
};

return service;

function activate() {
  service.onLogin.subscribe(function (userData) {
    console.info("user logged in");
  });

  service.onLogout.subscribe(function (userData) {
    console.info("Logging user out");
    dispose();
  });

  $window.addEventListener("offline", function () {
    console.info("Lost internet connection, going offline");
    service.isOnline.onNext(false);
  }, false);

  $window.addEventListener("online", function () {
    console.info("Regained internet connection, going online");
    service.isOnline.onNext(true);
  }, false);
}

function dispose() {
  angular.forEach(service, function (event, index) {
    if (service && service[event] && service[event].isDisposed === false) {
      service[event]();
    }
  });
}
```

}
    })();

I have a service that is waiting for that onLogin event to fire.  The code is simliar to:

```
(function () {
angular.module("app.data").service("offlineProjectDataService", OfflineProjectDataService);

function OfflineProjectDataService(definitions, metaDataService, userService, eventService) {
    "ngInject";

    var onLoginSubscription = eventService.onLogin.subscribe(function (isLoaded) {
        if (isLoaded) {
            activate();
        }
    });

    var service = {
        activate: activate
    }

    return service;

    function activate(){
        //..some stuff
    }
}
```

})();

The problem I'm having is that the onLogin event is not firing so my activate method is not being called.  If I move that exact same subscription line to some other controller in my app, it DOES fire. So I don't think there is anything wrong with syntax.

Unless of course I'm missing something here that is probably painfully obvious to somebody.

Comment: services need to be invoked and then the all you mention will fire. not just for inject they work automatically, you need to call any method of the service.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

## Use RxJS in a Service

Build a service with [RxJS Extensions for Angular](https://github.com/Reactive-Extensions/rx.angular.js).

```
<script src="//unpkg.com/angular/angular.js"></script>
<script src="//unpkg.com/rx/dist/rx.all.js"></script>
<script src="//unpkg.com/rx-angular/dist/rx.angular.js"></script>
```

```
var app = angular.module('myApp', ['rx']);

app.factory("DataService", function(rx) {
  var subject = new rx.Subject(); 
  var data = "Initial";
  
  return {
      set: function set(d){
        data = d;
        subject.onNext(d);
      },
      get: function get() {
        return data;
      },
      subscribe: function (o) {
         return subject.subscribe(o);
      }
  };
});
```

Then simply subscribe to the changes.

```
app.controller('displayCtrl', function(DataService) {
  var $ctrl = this;

  $ctrl.data = DataService.get();
  var subscription = DataService.subscribe(function onNext(d) {
      $ctrl.data = d;
  });

  this.$onDestroy = function() {
      subscription.dispose();
  };
});
```

Clients can subscribe to changes with `DataService.subscribe` and producers can push changes with `DataService.set`.

The [DEMO on PLNKR](https://plnkr.co/edit/YVKGhCx0DrzyzckMDjtv?p=preview).

Comment: I believe my actual issue was what Jesus Carrasco said above, but I think what you've shown is actually the solution I SHOULD be implementing.  I will start implementing it instead of the way I was doing it.